# OpenstreetMap Overpass API - Validate tag if present

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have this query

```
[out:json];

(
 way['addr:street'='Kurzenmoor']['addr:housenumber'='12']['addr:postcode'='25370']['addr:country'='DE'];
 node(around:700)['highway'='bus_stop'][!'ref'];
);

out;
```

This does not return a result due to the fact that the country has not been specified at the API.

This works:

```
[out:json];

(
 way['addr:street'='Kurzenmoor']['addr:housenumber'='12']['addr:postcode'='25370'];
 node(around:700)['highway'='bus_stop'][!'ref'];
);


out;
```

Is there a way to combine these? If there is no country present, I want the result, if there is a country present it should match the desired one (in this example "DE", if it matches, I want the result, otherwise I do not want it.

Comment: For asking questions about Overpass API consider using http://gis.stackexchange.com or http://help.openstreetmap.org/

Answer (score 0):

Overpass API is not a geocoder.

A better approach is to first determine the location via geocoding, e.g. by using [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), Photon or one of the other [OSM-based geocoders](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines). In the second step use Overpass API to find bus stops near this location.

Comment: How would using Nominatim help me in this case? If there are multiple results for the same postal code, how would I go about searching for the specific that I need? I still cannot simply pass in the country code as it might not be set in OpenStreetMap.

Also from what I see, the request returns multiple results but without any details on them, so I would have to manually get the detailed results for each place that has been returned. Or am I overseeing something?

Maybe you could provide an example code. 

Thanks

Comment: Another example:

`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?street=213 Brünner Straße&postalcode=1210&country=AT`

This does not return the desired building. However

`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?street=213 Brünner Straße&postalcode=1210`

does. So the issue is still there

Comment: Besides that, I would appreciate an answer to the original question due to the fact that there are different use cases for this functionality (checking if there is a result, otherwise performing another query, without another request to the api)

Comment: This looks like a bug. Did you consider reporting at https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/issues ?

Comment: I've reported this bug for you: https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/issues/1034

Comment: The bug has been fixed.